# Implementing GTM with existing ecommerce set up

Tags: google-tag-manager

We are currently in the process of setting up Google Tag Manager on our website. we already have Google UA set up with ecommerce working and some existing hard coded events.

My question (which I've google'd for hours and can't find a definite answer) is if remove my existing GA Tracking code (snippet and everything else), except for the ecommerce code, and install Google Tag Manager, but don't set up the ecommerce side of it, will it:

- still be able to tell me transactions even though it's now not being managed through GTM
- still work well inspite of the above reason
- still assign the income to sessions as I'm worried it'll just have a stack of conversions but not tell me their funnel / process to convert. *This one doesn't make as much sense to me as I'm considering the fact that the cookie should still be the same as all GTM is doing is managing the tags. I just need to confirm before I switch over from test to live.*

I'm pretty sure I'm ok on all fronts, due to cookies and all GTM doing is managing tags, but since I can't find anything about this anywhere, I just need to check how Google Tag Manager interacts with existing events and more importantly ecommerce tracking.

(For those who say we should just sort out the ecommerce side of Google Tag Manager.. finding a dev in my company with the capacity to do that won't be a easy job due to staffing limitations and this not being a priority)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Analytics Implementation and Inline GA on the same website.

You should probably use a named tracker (both in GTM and inline GA) - GTM creates Google Analytics Instances with random tracker names, while inline GA uses the default name "t0". If one some page you mix GTM and inline GA there may be side effects as calls go to different tracker instances (for example if you set a field or custom dimension it might be set only for the calls to one tracker instance and not the other).

If you can't change the inline code to a named tracker check the "Set tracker name" checkbox and leave the input field empty. Unless GTM changed this with the last update this should result in the default tracker name.

But other than that I do not why this would not work (and actually have used similar setups due to similar constraints as yours).

Further Reading:

- http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/01/21/gtm-existing-tracking/
- http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/ga-snippet-and-ga-gtm-tag-on-the-same-page/